# Loop leads to Timeout in array rotation

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, timeout

Hi how come swapping technique(my code) suffers Timeout where as circular array

`{(i+number of rotation)%length}` implementation does not?

`a` is an `int[]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberofrotation; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length-1; j++) {
        temp=a[j];
        a[j]=a[j+1];
        a[j+1]=temp;
    }
}
return a;
```

Comment: What do you mean by timeout. What is the other implementation you are referencing?

Comment: How big is the interger array? Does timeout mean gets stuck in the loop?

Comment: @Ben this code takes large values in an array and rotates left.It works fine but when inputs are of 4digit values and the rotation value is also large it encounters "Termination due to Timeout" error message.

Comment: Like hackerank or codility? Rather than locally?

Comment: The other method (circular array) it works fine for the above case.

Comment: You still did not explain the referenced implementation. I am assuming the timeout comes from the framework you are running your code in as this is not a standard Java thing. Why it is happening? Because your calculation is taking too long.

Comment: @doctorlove yeah it is from hackerrank

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by timeout

Comment: @NomanKhan this code fails to execute within the time specified.Correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(i+number of rotation)%length***   is to advance by number of rotations and wrap around to form circular array.
With modulo number of rotations are reduced to less than or equals to length of array, hence faster execution

To give you some idea...

Taking your approach of swapping array values,
if an array of length 10 is swapped by n times  where n is a multiple of 10 , 
means **n mod 10 = 0**, than result is original array.

If value of n is not a multiple of 10  than you will see array order change in array values.
you can get the result either by rotating n times,  or  same result can be achieved by rotating **n mod 10  times**

So if  n = 25  than swapping array by 25  is equivalent to swapping array 5 times

25 mod 10 = 5

similarly if n=13 , than swapping array by 13 time will have same result of swapping array 3 times

13 mod 10 = 3

Even if number of rotation is Integer.MAX_VALUE and length of array to rotate is 100,
number of rotations can be reduced to **Integer.MAX_VALUE%100** which is **47**.